# How to set the length of Object[]

Tags: java, arrays

Why this piece of code does not work? How to set the length of `Object[]`.

```
Object[] entry = new Object[]{};
entry[0] = 1;
entry[1] = "1";
```

Comment: Why all the downvotes?  It might be low-level, but it's a valid question when coming from a dynamic language background.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are Initializing a new array then you either have to specify its size explicitly using the syntax mentioned in the answer above:

```
Object[] entry = new Object[2];
```

or use the array initializer block what you presented in your question like this:

```
Object[] entry = new Object[] {"a", "b"};
```

What you did here was initializing an array to be empty thus setting its size to 0. If you print out the length of that array it will be 0.

If you want an array whose size can be modified you are advised to use the List interface (an ArrayList for example).

```
List<Object> myList = new ArrayList<Object>();
```

You can set the initial capacity of an ArrayList using its constructor:

```
List<Object> myList = new ArrayList<Object>(2);
```

List is generic so you should use the type parameter otherwise you will get some warnings.

If you don't know what objects will you store in your List you may do something like this:

```
List<?> myList = new ArrayList(2);
```

but you will get warnings that way.

More info about arrays: [Arrays](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html)

And about Lists: [List interface](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/List.html)

If you are interested in java Generics: [Generics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/index.html)

Answer (score 5):

You have to initialize the size of an Array. Either like this:

```
Object[] entry = new Object[2];
entry[0] = 1;
entry[1] = "1";
```

Or do it like this:

```
Object[] entry = new Object[] {1, "1"};
```

Cheers,
Max

Answer (score 3):

Specify the size like this:

```
Object[] entry = new Object[2];
```

You might want to read this tutorial: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html

Comment: Me too. I don't see any problems with this answer.

Answer (score 3):

You need to determine the size like this:

```
Object[] entry = new Object[2];
```

In your example:

```
Object[] entry = new Object[]{};
```

You are creating an array with length of 0, so `entry[0]` and `entry[1]` don't exist.

Answer (score 3):

Java arrays cannot be resized.

Either you create an array that can already hold your two objects, using `new Object[2]`,

or you use one of the collection classes, for example [`ArrayList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html):

```
ArrayList<Object> l = new ArrayList<Object>(); 
l.add(1);
l.add("1");
```

Comment: Lists are generic and they will generate warnings if not used that way. Your answer is not advised.

Comment: Something else: you should use List<Object> for the type declaration because one should use the most generic solution available. This way it will be easier to refactor your code.

Answer (score 1):

Just call `ensureCapacity` before setting value to array:

```
private Object[] ensureCapacity(Object[] array, int position) {
    return array.length <= position ? Arrays.copyOf(array, position + 1) : array;
}
```

I mean smth like this:

```
Object[] entry = new Object[]{};
entry = ensureCapacity(entry, 10);
entry[10] = 10;
```